# Replace first level array keys using values from a specific column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

I have an array like this

```
$users = array(
    [0] => array('Id' => 3, 'Name' => 'Bob'),
    [1] => array('Id' => 8, 'Name' => 'Alice'),
)
```

and I want to pull the Ids 'up' one level so that the final array is:

```
$usersById = array(
    [3] => array('Id' => 3, 'Name' => 'Bob'),
    [8] => array('Id' => 8, 'Name' => 'Alice'),
)
```

The Id values are unique.

Is there a native PHP way to do this? The code I'm currently using is:

```
$usersById = array();
foreach ($users as $key => $value)
{
    $usersById[$value['Id']] = $value;
}
```

This works, but is not terribly elegant.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Modern answer (requires PHP 5.5)

The new function [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is very versatile and one of the things it can do is exactly this type of reindexing:

```
// second parameter is null means we 're just going to reindex the input
$usersById = array_column($users, null, 'Id');
```

#### Original answer (for earlier PHP versions)

You need to fetch the ids from the sub-arrays with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), then create a new array with [`array_combine`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$ids = array_map(function($user) { return $user['Id']; }, $users);
$users = array_combine($ids, $users);
```

The code above requires PHP >= 5.3 for the anonymous function syntax, but you can also do the same (albeit it will look a bit uglier) with [`create_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) which only requires PHP >= 4.0.1:

```
$ids = array_map(create_function('$user', 'return $user["Id"];'), $users);
$users = array_combine($ids, $users);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/ZIaRq)**.

Comment: @hakre: To me as well, but this approach is another alternative for the OP (they did ask for one) and also much more scalable when things start getting hairy.

Comment: @Jon: I'm recently experimenting more and more by overloading the original value with a closure, like the second example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456837/php-array-reduce-to-sub-array-key/7457662#7457662

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) function, like:

```
$usersById = array_reduce($users, function ($reduced, $current) {
    $reduced[$current['Id']] = $current;
    return $reduced;
});
```

However, it's no more elegant than a `foreach`.

Comment: "However, it's no more elegant than a `foreach`." - except that it's declarative, the original `$users` array is not mutated, and you can dynamically pass through a callback to `array_reduce` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think using `foreach` is much more elegant. Maybe you just only want to write it differently:

```
$keyed = array();
foreach($users as $w) $keyed[$w['Id']] = $w;
```

In case you want to replace the existing array, `foreach` is not that flexible indeed. But maybe the following is some sort of alternative:

```
$users = function($key) use ($users)
{
    foreach($users as $v) $keys[] = $v[$key];
    return array_combine($keys, $users);
};
$users = $users('Id');
```

It allows the callback to accept parameters, e.g. the name of the key which should be used to create the new keys from.

Comment: +1, very nice. Although I wouldn't go so far as to overwrite the original variable, maybe `usersKeyedBy` would be a better name.

Answer (score 1):

And one more variant using array_walk:

```
$usersById = array();
array_walk($users, function($val) use (&$usersById) {
    $usersById[$val['Id']] = $val;
});
```